# vSphere/ESX How to log migration event to guest Windows OS

Tags: vmware-vsphere, migration, failover, windows-event-log

On a vSphere/ESX environment, how to write (automated) migration events to the eventlog into the hosted Windows VM that has been migrated?

So that the hosted OS is aware of the migration event, and thus any resulting issues can be related to that event?

In a perfect world there *should* be no issues, I know.

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange request... Mainly because there shouldn't be issues that result from vMotion *(manual or DRS-triggered)* in a vSphere environment.

**A vMotion should be safe.**

If there are issues stemming from it, you need to fix those instead of reacting to guest-level problems.

[image]

This doesn't answer your question directly, but you're chasing the symptom rather than the root issue.

---

In terms of tracking vMotion history, there are [PowerCLI options](http://www.lucd.info/2010/06/22/events-part-8-vmotion-history/) to extract that information. In addition, you can just look at the vCenter logs.

[image]

Comment: I was expecting your answer.
Yes, in a perfect world there should be no issues or bugs. But in the real world of imperfect software (I have yet to encounter a piece of software that is perfect) it is usually the symptoms, and plentiful logging that lead to a root issue, thus enabling the improvement of the software, on the path towards perfection.

Comment: Fix the VMware issues, then. Keep vSphere up-to-date and promote good design. A vMotion [*should be harmless*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/l3SBP.png).